# Counting total number of lines in final map reduce output in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

Currently my num reduce task is set to `job.setNumReduceTasks(100);`

So my final output directory is in S3 and looks like the following

```
/output/part-r-00000.gz
/output/part-r-00001.gz
... etc
```

in order to count all the lines I have to manually download and unzip all files and go through each file to count the total lines.

Is there a total line metric store somewhere in hadoop context?

Comment: _"I have to manually unzip all files and go through each file to count the total lines"_ -- Um, no .... `zcat /output/part*.gz|wc -l` for the total.

Comment: those files are in s3, I have to download them and `wc` which is a hassle since they are huge files, I was hoping that hadoop already store the info internally, if not I might have write another map reduce just for line count.

Comment: Ah, well you omitted some crucial info... please edit your post.

Comment: good call, let me edit it.

Comment: Have you tried using Spark or Hive to read the gzip files?

Comment: Did you try this command ? **hadoop fs -cat /path/to/hdfs/* | wc -l**

Answer (score 0):

Map Reduce application log stores counters for map and reduce tasks. For over all reducers ,if you look at the job logs (counters to be precise) something like "reduce output records " should provide you with the required info. However this is HDP platform where RM UI has all information in job counter section.